# simple excel code array issue

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

so i have 2 columns A and B with numbers in them, something like this.

```
A                   B
96.66666667         0
193.3333333         0
290                 0
386.6666667         0 
483.3333333         1
725                 22
966.6666667         19
1208.333333         10
```

What I want code for is to look at column B and if its value is 0, put nothing in say column C1.  If column B is >0, then take its corresponding value in A, and list the A value, B number of times.  So my final goal column in C would look like:

```
483.3333333333333
725
725
725
725
etc til 725 happens 22 times then
966
966
etc until 966 happens 19 times etc.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is this as small as your dataset and a one time thing? because if so, you can do without VBA. See `REPT` function (with added "," to cell value), `Text-To-Columns` and `Copy > Past > Transpose`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a fast solution without any later transposing you could use this:

```
Sub test()
  Dim values As Variant, counter As Variant
  values = [A1:A100].Value 'change the ranges to fit your needs
  counter = [B1:B100].Value

  Dim output() As Variant
  ReDim output(0 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(counter) - 1, 0)

  Dim i As Long, j As Long

  While i <= UBound(output)
    j = j + 1
    For i = i To counter(j, 1) + i - 1
      output(i, 0) = values(j, 1)
    Next
  Wend

  [C1].Resize(UBound(output) + 1).Value = output
  'change C1 to the cell to start your output

End Sub
```

It generates an array (`output`) which will simply be pasted starting with `C1` (can be changed)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this simple code:

```
Sub trasposeNumbers()
    Dim i
    For Each i In Range("B1:B100")
        If i.Value = 0 Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            Range(Cells(i.Row, 1), Cells(i.Row, i.Value)).Value = i.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This way you override the value in column B, just note that.